# What is the SQLServer way creating an in index like below?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

The line below work fine for Oracle but for SQLServer it doesnt work,

```
   CREATE INDEX IDX_1
      ON Table1
        (UID1,
         UID2,
         CONFIG,
         DATE,
         (UPPER(NAME)))
```

Currently this says incorrect index near '('.
Any ideas ? 
I have heard of Collate but not sure how that can be done using that.

Comment: Did you try with just `NAME` and not `UPPER(NAME)` ?

Comment: Yes it works like that - but that wouldnt be the same would it ?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support functions in indexes. For this, you might want to consider adding `UPPER(NAME)` as a computed column on the table and then applying an index to that - but you'll have to modify queries that rely on the function to use the computed column instead.

Comment: as @Damien_The_Unbeliever said

Comment: I wouldnt be able to changes the queries as there are too many, so it sounds like that it is not really possible the way I want to do this then...

Comment: You just have to change your `INSERT` queries and change `NAME` to `UPPER(NAME)`. That's not a very hard work, use a replace.

Comment: The queries are spread in mutiple enterprise solutions I cant just willy nilly replace things in the code, :) thanks for your help guys. @Damien_The_Unbeliever put your answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL Server alternative would be as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
    UID1 int not null,
     UID2 int not null,
     CONFIG int not null,
     DATE int not null, --:)
     NAME varchar(39) not null,
     UPPERNAME as UPPER(Name) PERSISTED
)
```

And then you could create an index:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_1
  ON Table1
    (UID1,
     UID2,
     CONFIG,
     DATE,
     UPPERNAME)
```

Unfortunately, for your queries to *benefit* from this index, they'd have to be modified to use `UPPERNAME` directly rather than using the `UPPER` function on the `NAME` column.

Comment: However when the column's collation is case insensitive, the comparison also by default will be case insensitive, so the UPPER may not be needed at all. We don't know that from the question.

Answer (score -1):

It should look something like this

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_1 on Table1
(
    [UID1] ASC,
    [UID2] ASC,
    ....
)WITH 
(PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
DROP_EXISTING   = OFF, 
ONLINE = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
```

As you see there are a lot of parameters you should get familiar with.

One way I would suggest for getting started is to create the index with 
SQL Server Management Studio UI assistant and then have the script created by 
using the button on top of the assistant, for me this was a good way of learning
this.
And I am not sure at present if creating an Index with a function call like UPPER is 
possible with SQL Server, but I really do not know if this is possible or not,
but I'd rather say no if you put a pistol on my chest ;o)

Comment: Already know how to do that - and that is not what i asked for. where is the UPPER in there ?

Comment: Well, if you want it like that, when you're question was not really clear at all...
I'd say you have to cope with an extra column where you fill in your UPPER text, but I just see that one guy already suggested that and you accepted it, so why bother with it any more ...